# Collect all values of a Set field

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a collection which has a field of type Set with some values. I need to create a new set collecting all these values.

I am wondering if this is possible using lambda expressions.

Below is the code line :

```
Set<String> teacherId = batches.stream()
                               .filter(b -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(b.getTeacherIds()))
                               .map(b -> b.getTeacherIds())
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The problem is post map operation, it contains a collection of set of strings. So collect operation returns a `Set<Set<String>>` but i am looking to aggregate all the values to a single set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) instead of `map`:

```
Set<String> teacherIds = 
    batches.stream()
           .flatMap(b -> b.getTeacherIds().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that the filtering is redundant for empty collections - streaming an empty collection will just result in an empty stream, which won't affect the final result.
If `getTeacherIds()` could return `null`, however, you'd still have to handle it. Using `filter(Objects::nonNull)` would suffice, and save you the dependency on Apache Commons.

Comment: What if the b.getTeacherIds is a null ?

Comment: @BiscuitCoder arg, good point - streams don't handle nulls well. I'll edit this in.

Comment: @Mureinik `filter(Objects::nonNull)` would not be enough. you would call `stream` inside `flatMap` on a null reference...

Comment: @Mureinik Flatmap does exactly what i needed here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap` to obtain a flat `Stream` of all the values, and then collect to a `Set<String>`:

```
Set<String> teacherId = 
    batches.stream()
           .filter(b -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(b.getTeacherIds()))
           .flatMap(b -> b.getTeacherIds().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I’d use the opportunity to get rid of this questionable utility method. If dealing with potential `null` is desired, it should be made explicit, `.filter(b -> b.getTeacherIds()!=null)`, empty lists are already handled by `flatMap`.

Comment: @Holger I have introduced the CollectionUtils.isEmpty in the question in the first place. But i do understand it is irrelevant to put an empty check and a mere null check would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you care that that `getTeacherIds()` is not null, use it explicitly via `!=`, that `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` just hides stuff. Especially since if `getTeacherIds()` returns an Empty collection - that is handled just fine by `flatMap`, so to me that is not needed at all.

```
  Set<String> teacherIds = batches
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getTeacherIds() != null)
            .flatMap(x -> x.getTeacherIds().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if this is possible using lambda expressions.

I capture the last fish, :).

```
Set<String> teacherIds = batches.stream()//v--- the class of `x`
                                .map(XClass::getTeacherIds)
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

*Note*: I'm sorry I'm forget to tell you if the `getTeacherIds` copy the internal IDs to a new set of IDs, the code above is appropriate for you. since it is read the IDs from `XClass` once.

Comment: Considering getTeacherIds can return null, does map handle the NPE ?

Comment: So map function iterates over the each element, collects what getTeacherIds returns for each element and composes a stream of getTeacherIds results. From there on it is straightforward. Am i getting this right ?

Comment: @BiscuitCoder yes, you are right. `map` doesn't throws NPE, NPE occurs in `flatMap`.

Comment: @BiscuitCoder Not at all.